# ANOVA after using glm.fit

Tags: r, glm, anova

I would like to perform a likelihood ratio test to determine the power of a model term in a DOE.  Till now I have been using the p-value from the glm fit to do this and things have been fine.  As I started to use the anova function, I realized that there does not seem to be an anova function designed to accept the input from a glm.fit function, only a glm function.  Here is an example of what I would like to do:

```
X # This is a model matrix from matrix.model
y # These are the y values for the fit
tfit = glm.fit(X, y, family = poisson())
anova(tfit, test = 'LRT')
```

Typically I would assume that the `anova` function call would just need to be altered to `anova.glm`, but that is not the case.  How can I get the `glm.fit` function output to be compatible with an `anova` function input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `glm.fit` does not output of class `glm`, but a raw list with all kinds of data about the model. This cannot be fed to `anova.glm` since this function expects an object of class `glm` as produced by the `glm` function. If you have the raw data available (thus not turned in to a model matrix, you can apply the `glm` function to this to produce the desired outcome.

```
X <- matrix(c(runif(10), rnorm(10)), ncol = 2)
y <- round(runif(10, 1, 5))
X.mm <- model.matrix(y ~ X)
model.fit.1 <- glm.fit(X.mm, y, family = poisson())
class(model.fit.1)
model.fit.2 <- glm(y ~ X, family = "poisson")
class(model.fit.2)

anova(model.fit.2, test = "LRT")
```

If you can't use the `glm` function and must use the `glm.fit` then you can construct the LRT yourself from the `glm.fit` output. For a start take the following function

```
LRT.glm.fit <- function(glm.fit.mod){
  df.null <- glm.fit.mod$df.null
  df.mod <- glm.fit.mod$df.residual
  dev.null <- glm.fit.mod$null.deviance
  dev.mod <- glm.fit.mod$deviance
  dev.diff <- dev.null - dev.mod
  p.value <- 1 - pchisq(dev.null - dev.mod, df.null - df.mod)
  output <- c(round(df.null), round(df.mod), dev.null, dev.mod, p.value)
  names(output) <- c("df.null", "df.mod", "dev.null", "dev.mod", "p.value")
  output
}
```

Comment: I would like to not require the raw data and would rather have the model matrix passed through...  This is for a MC power calculation routine.  Is there a way do to it without needing the glm object?